# How to set RadioButton.IsChecked, if it's Content got focus

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In my WPF app, I have a group of `RadioButton`s, where one of the elements is defined like this:

```
<RadioButton Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
                Margin="5"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                GroupName="GroupDatetimeTo">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="5,5,15,5"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="Exactly">
        </TextBlock>

        <mah:DateTimePicker Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="5"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            SelectedDateTime="{Binding Path=DatetimeTo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        </mah:DateTimePicker>
    </Grid>
</RadioButton>
```

I would expect that when `DateTimePicker` control gets focused - `RadioButton` would automatically become checked. However, that doesn't happen. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Binding checked state

You can add a binding to the `IsChecked` property that monitors the keyboard focus of `DateTimePicker`.

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=MyDateTimePicker, Mode=OneWay, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" ... >
```

Here, `MyDateTimePicker` is the name of the `DateTimePicker` in your `RadioButton`.

```
<mahapps:DateTimePicker x:Name="MyDateTimePicker" ... />
```

This solution is not applicable, if you need to bind `IsChecked` otherwise.

### Check on focused attached property

Another solution is to create an attached property that can be enabled to supervise when the control that it is attached to gets the keyboard focus. Then, it searches up the visual tree to find the parent `RadioButton` and sets `IsChecked` to `true`. This way, you can still bind the property.

```
public static class RadioButtonProperties
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckOnFocusProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "CheckOnFocus", typeof(bool), typeof(RadioButtonProperties), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnCheckOnFocusChanged));

   private static void OnCheckOnFocusChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      if (!(d is FrameworkElement frameworkElement))
         return;

      if ((bool)e.NewValue)
         frameworkElement.GotKeyboardFocus += OnGotKeyboardFocus;
      else
         frameworkElement.GotKeyboardFocus -= OnGotKeyboardFocus;
   }

   public static bool GetCheckOnFocus(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
   {
      return (bool)dependencyObject.GetValue(CheckOnFocusProperty);
   }

   public static void SetCheckOnFocus(DependencyObject dependencyObject, bool value)
   {
      dependencyObject.SetValue(CheckOnFocusProperty, value);
   }

   private static void OnGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      var radioButton = FindParent<RadioButton>((DependencyObject)sender);
      if (radioButton != null)
         radioButton.IsChecked = true;
   }

   private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
   {
      var parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

      if (parentObject == null)
         return null;

      if (parentObject is T parent)
         return parent;

      return FindParent<T>(parentObject);
   }
}
```

To enable it, set the attached `CheckOnFocus` property to `True` on the target `DateTimePicker`.

```
<mahapps:DateTimePicker local:RadioButtonProperties.CheckOnFocus="True" ...>
```